# Puppet r10k: get deploykey into control-repo

Tags: ssh, puppet, r10k

I have a control-repo in gitlab and I want to automatically generate an sshkey and send it to my repository throu the gitlab api(using Deploy Token).

It is actually a straight forward question I want answered. What is the (or is there any)"standard" with puppet on how to send an sshkey to gitlab via its api? I have tried using this module(https://forge.puppet.com/abrader/gms), but it doest work. Below I explain what I have done and tried.

I have generated a deploy token by going to Settings->Repository->Deploy Tokens. Here I got a random string that I have now saved.

I have been able to automatically generate a key named 'manager-deploy-key'. I use this module to generate the key: https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/ssh_keygen

Ssh-keygen code

```
ssh_keygen { 'root':
  bits     => 4096,
  type     => 'rsa',
  filename => '/root/.ssh/manager-deploy-key',
}
```

I then wanted to use this module: "https://forge.puppet.com/abrader/gms" to automatically send the newly generated key to my repo as a deploy key.

Should send deploykey

```
git_deploy_key { 'add_deploy_key_to_puppet_control':
  ensure       => present,
  name         => $::fqdn,
  path         => '/root/.ssh/manager-deploy-key.pub',
  token        => 'DEPLOY_TOKEN_HERE',
  project_name => 'user/control-repo',
  server_url   => 'https://gitlab.com',
  provider     => 'gitlab',
}
```

This failed and therefore I chose to debug by adding --debug in my command --> "puppet apply --debug /file/test.pp"

Looking into the debugging information the response to the GET request is

```
"{\"error\":\"API V3 is no longer supported. Use API V4 instead.\"}"
```

The module doesnt work... Therefore I am now about to use curl to automate this myself. However, I really want to know if there is an easier alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only way really is to use curl since the module is deprecated. I have set up a command for it if someone needs an example.

```sh
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${git_api_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST -d "{\"title\":\"${git_ssl_keyname}\",\"key\":\"${sslpub}\", \"can_push\":\"true\"}"     \
    "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/deploy_keys"
```

**git_api_token** is a token you generate on your account. I was unable to make this work with a deploy token that you can generate in a project.

**git_ssl_keyname** is the name of your ssh key. This can be anything you want.

**sslpub** is the actual key you want imported into your project.

**project_id** is the id of your project. If you visit your main project page it will be near the top.

If you want more information on gitlabs access token api visit https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deploy_keys.html